# How to sort the row contents on table cell by using date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, date

i am new to iphone application development.i am developing RSS feed Reader it has number of different RSS feeds. In my application (XML parsing),

1. i want to display the content of the row on cell for particular date and with their corresponding title, description (in my application, i am using three labels for displaying title, date and description) on table view cell after parsing xml data.
2. And i want to sort the all kinds of RSS feeds row contents(title, date, description) depends upon the date in single another UIViewController and for each RSS feed has a separate ViewController. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the data into a NSMutableArray of NSDictionary items, and then sort the array by each key. When you parse the XML data, you store the data in the array, and resort the array as needed.